# Concat objects is not working or I need to convert values to the right format?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, object

I need to get `data.entities.paises` from the first `$.post` and `concat()` with `data.entities` from the second `$.post` and this is how I'm doing:

```
  var paisesFromEntity;

  $.post(Routing.generate('productoGuardarPasoCinco'), $form.serialize(), 'json').done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    if (data.entities !== "undefined" || data.entities != "") {
      paisesFromEntity = data.entities.paises;
    }
  }).fail(function () {
      return false;
  });

  var returnList = function (entities) {
      if (entities.length > 0) {
          var items = [];
          entities.forEach(function (value, index, array) {
              items.push(value.pais);
          });

          return items.join(', ');
      }
  };

  var fullList = [];

  $.post(Routing.generate('agregarPaisesDistribuidor'), $form.serialize(), 'json').done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
      fullList = fullList.concat(data.entities, JSON.stringify(paisesFromEntity));
      var displayText = returnList(fullList);
      $('#td-' + data.idToUpdate).html(displayText);
  }).fail(function () {
      return false;
  });
```

Taking this output for first `$.post()`:

```
{
   "success":true,
   "entities":{
      "id":13,
      "nombre":"dsdsfsdfsd",
      "direccion":"fsdfsdfsdf",
      "telefono":"4234234",
      "paises":[
         "Bolivia",
         "Costa Rica",
         "Ecuador"
      ]
   }
}
```

And the this for the second `$.post()`:

```
{
   "success":true,
   "entities":[
      {
         "pais":"Colombia"
      },
      {
         "pais":"Panam\u00e1"
      },
      {
         "pais":"Ciudad del Vaticano"
      }
   ],
   "idToUpdate":"14"
}
```

The expected output in `displayText` should be something like: `Bolivia, Costa Rica,  Ecuador, Colombia, Panam\u00e1, Ciudad del Vaticano` but I get this output instead `Colombia, Panamá, Ciudad del Vaticano,` and some values are missing the ones from `data.entities.paises`. I suspect the error is that `data.entities.paises` is not in the same format as `data.entities` and for that the function on `returnList` doesn't do the job god, so where is the error on the `concat()` function or on the `data.entities.paises` format? If is the second one how can I convert to the same format as `data.entities` before concatenate both?

Comment: So you want the final result to be an array (or a string combined with ",") that has all 6 of the pais? The 3 returned as elements of an array in the first `$.post` and the 3 returned as values in an array of objects from the second `$.post`?

Comment: @deitch a string combined with `,` but from both results, take into account that JSON is dynamic it comes from server side

Comment: I get it. I will post an answer below (if someone doesn't get to it first)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 3 issues here.

First of all, you can have a timing issue, since there is no guarantee that the first `$.post` will finish before the second. You need to ensure **both** are finished before moving in. You have a few ways to do that - chaining, caolan's async lib https://github.com/caolan/async, callbacks that check, etc. - but that is not what you are asking about here.

The second issue is that the first response is an array of strings; the second is an array of objects whose values you want, and you need to combine them.

The third issue is that you are converting the array of strings to JSON string, which will not work either.

Try this.

```
// assuming data.entities is an array of objects, and paisesFromEntity is an array of strings
fullList = fullList.concat(paisesFromEntity, getValues(data.entities));
```

The `getValues()` function

```
getValues = function(arr){
  var ret = [], i;
  for (i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
     ret.push(arr[i].pais);
  }
  return(ret);
};
```

If you are doing this in jQuery, you can use

```
getValues = function(arr){
  var ret = [];
  $.each(arr,function(i,entry) {
    ret.push(entry.pais);
  });
  return(ret);
};
```

If you have access to lodash or underscore, it is even easier with pluck.

Comment: Around the issues, I have not problems with include caolan async library, can you improve your question taking my code as example for what you're talking about? I've use this approach on some many parts on a site and I need to take care of this right now

Comment: It might be easier to just ask a new question, "how do I manage timing dependencies with multiple parallel `$.post` and async lib?" If you link to it here, I will answer it there, although I suspect someone else will get it first. :-)

Comment: done, take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27127758/how-do-i-manage-timing-dependencies-with-multiple-parallel-post-and-async-lib)