# How do I manage timing dependencies with multiple parallel $.post and async lib?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous

I've this jQuery code where second `$.post()` relies on first `$.post()` execution and this could be a problem if first one is not done yet or fail during execute or second one start before. Maybe I could use some kind of chained calls for a workaround but I think is not pretty at all. How do I get ride of this using for exammple [Coalan Async](https://github.com/caolan/async)?

```
  var paisesFromEntity;

  $.post(Routing.generate('productoGuardarPasoCinco'), $form.serialize(), 'json').done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    if (data.entities !== "undefined" || data.entities != "") {
      paisesFromEntity = data.entities.paises;
    }
  }).fail(function () {
      return false;
  });

  var returnList = function (entities) {
      if (entities.length > 0) {
          var items = [];
          entities.forEach(function (value, index, array) {
              items.push(value.pais);
          });

          return items.join(', ');
      }
  }, 
  fullList = [],
  getValues = function(arr){
      var ret = [];
      $.each(arr,function(i,entry) {
           ret.push(entry.pais);
      });
      return(ret);
  }; 

  $.post(Routing.generate('agregarPaisesDistribuidor'), $form.serialize(), 'json').done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
      fullList = fullList.concat(paisesFromEntity, getValues(data.entities));
      $('#td-' + data.idToUpdate).html(returnList(fullList));
  }).fail(function () {
      return false;
  });
```

Comment: You've answered your own question. If you wish to use the [linked library](https://github.com/caolan/async), just read its documentation. Don't post a question on SO asking somebody else to implement your feature.

Comment: @hon2a it was an offshoot of another question. I suggested that modifying the answer would distract, so asked him to break it out.

Comment: That doesn't change the fact that the OP should do his own research on [using Promises](http://joseoncode.com/2011/09/26/a-walkthrough-jquery-deferred-and-promise/) before putting the issue here.

Comment: @hon2a, yeah, I know, but it was an offshoot, and I was trying to be helpful. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested, the async lib is just fabulous - on node server-side or in the browser. Here is the lib https://github.com/caolan/async

Since you are doing these in parallel, you want to do:

```
function doLotsOfStuff(done) {
    async.parallel([
       function(cb) {
         $.post(Routing.generate('productoGuardarPasoCinco'), $form.serialize(), 'json').done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
           if (data.entities !== "undefined" || data.entities != "") {
             cb(null,data.entities.paises);
           } else {
             cb();
           }
         }).fail(function () {
           cb("error");
         });
       },
       function(cb) {
         $.post(Routing.generate('agregarPaisesDistribuidor'), $form.serialize(), 'json').done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
             cb(null,getValues(data.entities));
         }).fail(function () {
             cb("error");
         });
       }
    ],function(err,results) {
      var fullList = [].concat(results[0], results[1]);
      $('#td-' + data.idToUpdate).html(returnList(fullList));
      done();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

your code could become

```
var paisesFromEntity;

  var deferred1 = $.post(Routing.generate('productoGuardarPasoCinco'), $form.serialize(), 'json');

  var returnList = function (entities) {
      if (entities.length > 0) {
          var items = [];
          entities.forEach(function (value, index, array) {
              items.push(value.pais);
          });

          return items.join(', ');
      }
  }, 
  fullList = [],
  getValues = function(arr){
      var ret = [];
      $.each(arr,function(i,entry) {
           ret.push(entry.pais);
      });
      return(ret);
  }; 

  var deferred2 = $.post(Routing.generate('agregarPaisesDistribuidor'), $form.serialize(), 'json');

  $.when(deferred1, deferred2)
  .then(function(resp1, resp2) {
    if (resp1[0].entities !== "undefined" || resp1[0].entities != "") {
      paisesFromEntity = resp1.entities.paises;

      fullList = fullList.concat(paisesFromEntity, getValues(resp2[0].entities));
      $('#td-' + data.idToUpdate).html(returnList(fullList));
    }
  });
```